# Monodroid Debug Won't Display Strings Over 100 Characters

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, xamarin.android

I'm having trouble seeing my full string variables in debug mode on a Monodroid project.

This happens when I hover over the string variable, also when in the immediate window when I ask for it's value.  Only the first 100 characters are displayed followed by a ... (three ellipses)

Below is an image demonstrating the problem.  This doesn't happen in a "normal" .net project, only one's targeting monodroid profile.  I could live with the hover not working but the fact that the immediate window is failing me is extremely frustrating.  Any workarounds?

I am using Visual Studio 2010, Mono-For-Android v4.0.3.

[Update Direct Link to Image Since It Is Not Legible](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20210444/brokenDebug.png)

[broken debug http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20210444/brokenDebug.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20210444/brokenDebug.png)

EDIT:  I've figured out a workaround but would appreciate something more elegant than 
typing ?myString.Substring(x) into the immediate window.

Comment: You should enter your workaround as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a change made to the debugging library that I was unaware of.  I have turned it off for the 4.2 release.

Comment: Thanks, is 4.2 available for download?  I could not find it.  Beta quality would be fine.

Comment: No, I just found out about this and made the fix today when you posted this.  :)

Comment: OK, thanks,  I'll look forward to the next push.  I can get by for now.